# Unable to send private message to target socket id

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am unable to get two users chatting to each other despite reducing the complexity and the potential code that could have caused the issue.

I am able to emit to all connected sockets so I have established it's not an issue in context of emit/on structure but rather; coming from the way i'm handling the private socket ids.

I have tried various versions of trying to send the private message to the correct socket id; I have tried older ways such as socket.to and the current way from the docs which is io.to(sockid).emit('event' message); all these variations have been unable to help me. I have consoled out the socket id I have on my Angular client side by printing    console.log('THIS IS MY SOCKET '+this.socket.id) and comparing it to the value I have in Redis using redis-cli and they both match perfectly every time which doesn't give me too much to go on.

**problem arises here:**

```
        if (res === 1) {
            _active_users.get_client_key(recipient)
                .then(socket_id => {
                    console.log('======='+io.sockets.name)
                    console.log('I am sending the message to: '+ recipient + 'and my socket id is'+ socket_id)
                //    socket.to(socket_id)socket.emit('incoming', "this is top secret"
                io.of('/chat').to(socket_id).emit('incoming', "this is top secret")

                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log("COULD NOT RETRIEVE KEY: " + error)
                })
```

Here is the link to the pastebin with more context:
https://pastebin.com/fYPJSnWW
The classes I import are essentially just setters and getters for handling the socket id you can think of them as just a worker class that handles Redis actions.

Expected: To allow two clients to communicate based on just their socket ids.

Actual:
am able to emit to all connected sockets and receive the expected results but the problem arises when trying to send to a specific socket id from a unknown reason.

Comment: Have you tried to put every part in a single line then debug it to see what has been set and what not? ie. `var ofchat = io.of('/chat');` then `var touser = ofchat.to(socket_id);` then `touser.emit('blah', "blah");` Also please add semi-colons to the end of your lines, I cringe if I don't see them for some reason

Comment: In this page `https://socket.io/docs/` I see they are using `socket.emit('request', /* */); // emit an event to the socket` for single socket, and `io.emit('broadcast', /* */); // emit an event to all connected sockets` for all sockets. then `socket.on('reply', function(){ /* */ }); // listen to the event`

Comment: I had an update; I know where the issue is coming from which helps - My Angular app or browser is opening up 3 or so connections leading to different socket ids. I do not know why it's doing this as I have not refresh the page or anything in these scenarios so still trying to figure this out.

Comment: https://stackabuse.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js/ try and create a global variable array, in which you push all your created sockets, `var touser = ofchat.to(socket_id);`, add all of those to the array. You can set a custom ID you know for each `var arrItem = new { id: socket_id, socket: ofchat.to(socket_id) };`

Comment: It wouldn't solve this issue of multiple connection issues though as the socket id is volatile; it needs to be enforced somehow to create something static to identify with.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. Your answer makes sense :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was coming from my front end.. I hope nobody has a headache like this! but here is what happened; when you're digging your own hole you often don't realise how deep you got yourself if you don't take the time to look around. I had two instances of the sockets. I instantiated both and used the one to connect and the other to send the message; which of course you cannnot do if you want things to work properly. So what I did was created only one instance of the socket in and and passed that ref of the socket around where I needed it which is ( sendMessage(username, socket) getMessage(socket)

```
 ngOnInit(     

this.socket = io.connect('localhost:3600',{
      reconnection: true,
      reconnectionDelay: 1000,
      reconnectionDelayMax : 5000,
      reconnectionAttempts: Infinity});
```